# Plotting time series in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, time-series, plot

I have a shapefile with points, like this:

```
x, y, id, data 
-1.3345,-0.4760, 1, data.csv
```

The `data.csv` contains:

```
date, data
2020-01-01, 1
2020-01-02, 2
2020-01-03, 3
2020-01-04, 4
```

How can I plot the data from the CSV file in QGIS?

Comment: Is there a different csv for each point?

Comment: What do you mean by "plotting a time series"? An animation? A static map with points for all timestamps? A series of static maps for each timestamp?

Comment: There is a csv for every point. When I select a point feature I want to see graph with on the x-axis the date and on the y-axis the data(values). Preferably when I select multiple point feature, I want to see the data of multiple point in one graph.

Comment: have you looked at the DataPlotly plugin? it lets you create scatter and line plots etc - not sure if you can link it to selected features but its a start.

Comment: Thank you, I can work with that :).